# Cloud build API deploy:run on Google Apps Script doesn't work

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I confirmed authorization with service account on GAS. "list" is work, but "run" method never work. Error msg is "source must not be empty". What kind of json should I attach?

This is on standalone GAS using GSApp library. （Apps-Script-GSApp-Library : MJ5317VIFJyKpi9HCkXOfS0MLm9v2IJHf）

```
function deploy() {
  var jsonKey = JSON.parse(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("jsonKey"));
  var serverToken = new GSApp.init(jsonKey.private_key, ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"], jsonKey.client_email);
  var tokens = serverToken.addUser(jsonKey.client_email).requestToken().getTokens();
  var url = "https://cloudbuild.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{ProjectId}/triggers/{TriggerId}:run";
  var options = {
    "muteHttpExceptions": true,
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {
      "Authorization":"Bearer "+tokens[jsonKey.client_email].token,
    },
    "source": {
      "projectId": "{ProjectId}",
      "branchName": "master",
      "repoName": "repo"
      }
  }
  Logger.log(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options));
}
```

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "source must not be empty",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`UrlFetchApp.fetch()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object)) does not recognize "**source**" as a valid property. Use "**payload**" instead. Also you'll need to `JSON.stringify()` your payload and set the `contentType` property as `application/json` as follows:

```
var options = {
    "muteHttpExceptions": true,
    "method": "POST",
    "contentType":"application/json",
    "headers": {
        "Authorization":"Bearer "+tokens[jsonKey.client_email].token,
    },
    "payload": JSON.stringify({
        "projectId": "{ProjectId}",
        "branchName": "master",
        "repoName": "repo"
    })

};
```